TypeError: face_detection.FaceDetection is not a constructor in React/Vite Production Build
I'm implementing face detection using MediaPipe in a React/TypeScript application with Vite. While the code works perfectly in development mode (npm run dev), I'm getting a constructor error when building and serving the production build (npm run build).
Uncaught TypeError: face_detection.FaceDetection is not a constructor
at main-CLsce9aG.js:31922:48179
at Qj (main-CLsce9aG.js:38:27193)
at Hk (main-CLsce9aG.js:38:47511)
at main-CLsce9aG.js:38:45609
at X_ (main-CLsce9aG.js:23:1729)
at MessagePort.p2 (main-CLsce9aG.js:23:2141)

Here is my code:
import  * as FaceDetection from '@mediapipe/face_detection';

export const useFaceDetection= ( options: FaceDetectionOptions = {}): UseFaceDetectionReturn => {

 useEffect(() => {
const faceDetection = new FaceDetection.FaceDetection({
  locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_detection@0.4/${file}`;
  }
});
....
...Rest
}

Question
1.Why is the FaceDetection constructor not available in the production build?
2.How can I properly initialize MediaPipe Face Detection in a Vite/React production build?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
